# Use images in Java Beans

Tags: java, jsp, url, javabeans

I try to create a PDF with iText within my JSP-Application and want to insert an image.

The file is located in my webapp-directory under:

```
http://localhost:8087/Buran/Symbols/Logos/dobi1.jpg
```

It's no problem to use it in html or jsp-files but within the bean it just does not work. To get the correct path by trial and error I created a test-file to see from which directory I had to start. Unfortunately that's not really what I expected it to be:

```
./apache-tomcat-7.0.41/bin/testfile.test
```

I got a recommendation to use:

```
private final String dobiurl = "/Buran/Symbols/Logos/dobi1.jpg";
URLConnection connection;
/**/
        try {
            connection = new URL(dobiurl).openConnection();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Etikette.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

But just cause errors...

Comment: Did you try putting the absolute path in `dobiurl` ? Also, what error do you get ?

Comment: @fxm: I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but I guess the absolute path would be:
http://localhost:8087/Buran/Symbols/Logos/dobi1.jpg
`java.io.IOException: java.awt.Image fetch aborted or errored`

For:
~/NetBeansProjects/Buran/src/main/webapp/Symbols/Logos/dobi1.jpg
`java.io.IOException: java.awt.Image fetch aborted or errored`

For that code:
`awtImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(dobiurl);
img = com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(awtImage, null);`

Comment: the absolute path is the path on the machine (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29). Did you try the solution provided here : http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Getting-java-awt-Image-fetch-aborted-or-errored-when-I-try-to-use-a-url-to-access-images-td2162818.html ?

Comment: Now I've tried:
file:///home/mario/NetBeansProjects/Buran/src/main/webapp/Symbols/Logos/dobi1.jpg
Then as suggested by jlopes151: 
file:/home...

But yes, I've seen that post already and wouldn't call it a "solution". They just came to the conclusion the problem is (as mine...) Not iText-Related.
Also it's an issue with the absolute path: Right now I am working on my test-environment. I don't think I want to stick with absolute paths...